# What is the best way to achive realtime info on my website currently using php yii framework and django-rest for api with mysql

Tags: php, python, node.js, django, socket.io

Here i have no idea, what to exactly use to get the real-time information on the web page on my already developed application. The real-time feature will be based on online Auction feature, as a bidder bids low/high amount all the concerned user should reflect the newer price on their window immediately without refreshing the web page.

Please suggest me the best way possible, my application based on:
PHP 5 frontend with yii 1.1.15 framework
Python django-rest framework for the rest api to fetch data from mysql database.

for this i have heard about the node js, but will it be possible using only node js without using mongodb/rethinkdb angular or express js or socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need bout Yii and Python? DRF is very easy to use and will provide the backend to provide a rest API and the front end can be something as simple as HTML/CSS/js to fetch data from the REST API. Yii will not add any value to this system.
You need to read up on how [an API based system works](https://codeburst.io/building-an-api-with-django-rest-framework-and-class-based-views-75b369b30396) works (which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey kmcodes, my application is already developed using these (yii, python etc)... now we want to add the realtime information display to some of its pages and i have no idea how to start with and what to use for that, please suggest in that way, Thanks